# Find which processes are using the dedicated video card

Tags: linux, graphics-card, process, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

I'm working on a simple Bumblebee GUI tool. One of its features is to show a list of processes which are currently using the dedicated video card. For now I list all of the running processes and check for their parent: if the parent process is `optirun` it means that this process is using the dedicated video card.

The issue is that this is not working with `primusrun`, as there isn't any process called like that while a program is launched with `primusrun program_name`. Is there anyway to detect the processes launched by primusrun or the processes which are using the dedicated video card? Thanks.

(This is more a programming-related question and maybe it belongs to StackOverflow, but I'm not interested in code example but a generic way to find these processes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try looking at which processes have GPU device nodes open (like `fuser -v /dev/nvidiactl`), but it's a costly operation (proportional to the total number of open files in the system).  A more efficient (but very hard to implement) approach would probably involve discovering programs connected to Bumblebee's secondary X using netlink; xlsclients wouldn't cut it because it lists windows, not connected clients.  It's also Bumblebee-specific, while using device nodes would allow you to discover discrete GPU users for PRIME offloading as well.

Please don't hesitate to use Bumblebee/primus issue trackers for such questions.  It's a relatively obscure topic, so contacting directly increases chances of obtaining an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try this. Meanwhile I did a loop through all the running processes and check if LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /proc/PID/environ contains the string "primus" (/usr/$LIB/primus), but I'm not really sure if this is a good approach.